# SqlAlchemy : delete, update through an association proxy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, sql-delete, model-associations

I would like to know what is the best way to use an association proxy for the update and delete operation :

I have a class `Person`  which can have some `tickets` as association
so I do `Person.tickets.append(ticket1)`

now can I do as well `Person.tickets.remove(ticket1)` ? Or `Person.tickets.clear()` ?
I tried both and it works, however I'm not sure it is the proper way...

Comment: If it works, what exactly is the problem you are facing? Both seem to be public methods, so you can evaluate the trade-offs by looking at the implementation.

Comment: yes it works, to do tickets.remove(ticket1). or what so ever. however I'm asking because i m not sure it is the proper way to delete something using an assoication proxy. I read somewhere that it is not the advised method for deletion, so I wanted feedbacks

Comment: Don't know why deleting as such should be avoided. I do it all the time. You have to be careful though. Association proxies aren't as flexible as, say instance methods, because they have to be instantiated at class-creation time of the class you put them on. In order to have the correct `Session` instance you have to use `object_session` to get it from the current model instance (which gets passed into the proxy). Anything with a global `Session` will bite you at some point. The re-usability of them is great though.